# ASP.NET version for IIS virtual directory keeps resetting from version 2.0 to 1 when iis is restarted

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an ASP.NET website that i want to deploy to IIS 6.0. When i set the sites ASP.NET version to 2.0, the setting reverts to 1.0 when IIS is restarted. There are two other ASP.NET sites on the same server whose version setting is being maintained across IIS restarts.

So this problem seem to be affecting only new sites being created. I'm just wondering if i need to re-register iis or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's why: one of your apps runs .net 2.0, while another runs 1.0, and they are using the same application pool. App pools are designed to run only 1 .net version. Unfortunately, this restriction isn't validated during setup time, but errors happen on runtime.

So, check that. Create another app pool for one of the .net versions.